# How to generate IP list from range IP start and end IP

Tags: vb.net, ip

I want to generate all list of IP addresses between two IPs start IP and IP

```
 textbox1.text = startiprange = "192.168.0.0"
 textbox2.text = endiprange = "192.168.255.255"
```

How to do this with simple way ?

Comment: Looks like you've not even bothered trying ... Show your code and tell where you've got the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    'start and end ip address
    Dim startiprange As Net.IPAddress = Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.0")
    Dim endiprange As Net.IPAddress = Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.255.255")

    'reverse address bytes for conversion to integer
    Dim strtip() As Byte = startiprange.GetAddressBytes
    Array.Reverse(strtip)
    Dim endip() As Byte = endiprange.GetAddressBytes
    Array.Reverse(endip)

    'convert
    Dim ips As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(strtip, 0)
    Dim ipe As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(endip, 0)

    'then loop from start to end
    For anip As UInt32 = ips To ipe
        'convert to bytes
        Dim ipbyt() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(anip)
        'reverse and create ip address
        Array.Reverse(ipbyt)
        Dim ipaddr As New Net.IPAddress(ipbyt)
        Debug.WriteLine(ipaddr.ToString)
    Next
```